# How to find the length of a segment which connects two triangles in a rhomboid?

Tags: euclidean-geometry

The problem is as follows:

[image: Sketch of the problem]

The alternatives in my book are as follows:

$\begin{array}{ll}
1.&\textrm{1 cm}\\
2.&\textrm{3 cm}\\
3.&\textrm{5 cm}\\
4.&\textrm{6 cm}\\
\end{array}$

I was only able to spot on:

$\triangle APT$ then $AT= 5$

Then:

$CT=4\cdot5=20$

But that's it. What else to do from here?.

What I attempted to find is some way to get:

$\frac{TO}{TC}=\frac{OR}{QC}$

However none of those segments seem to be known. *How can this be solved relying only in euclidean geometry postulates?*.

If possible please include a drawing in the answer so I can spot if a construction is needed.

Comment: Please do [not use pictures as a substitute of typing text](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20529/290189) of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not viewable to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

- $\triangle APT$ is similar to both $\triangle CQT$ and $\triangle ORT$
- $O$ is the midpoint of $AC$
- Try to find the lengths of $AC$ and thus $CO$ and $OT$
- Then find the lengths of $CQ$ and thus $OR$

Comment: $Q$ is useless. Once we have $OT$ we can find $OR$ using similar triangles.

Comment: @player3236 strictly speaking it may be unnecessary but it helps as a check of the ratios $1:\frac32:  4$

Answer (score 0):

$APT$ right triangle

$AP=4; PT=3$

$AT = 5$ Pythagoras' theorem

$CT=4AT=20\to AC=25$

$OA=25/2=12.5$

$OT=OA-AT=12.5-5=7.5$

Triangles $ATP$ and $OTR$ are similar

$OR/OT=AP/AT$

$OR=AP/AT OT=4/5 7.5$

$OR=6$